# How can I assign the value of textbox as part of dropdown value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have `GridView` `DropDownList`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employer">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="txtEmployer" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="AllScripts">AllScripts</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Contractor">Contractor</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtEmployer" ErrorMessage="*"
            InitialValue="Select"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And a `TextBox`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Other">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" TabIndex="435"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtOther" ErrorMessage="*"
            SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The `TexBox`, by default, is hidden on `PageLoad`.

When a user selects the "Other" option, the `TextBox` becomes visible allowing the user to enter whatever value he/she wants. This works good so far.

We can successfully collect the value of the `DropDownList` and insert into the database successfully.

However, we are trying to figure out how to insert the value of `txtOther` `TextBox` and insert as part of the `DropDownList`. Hopefully, this last sentence makes sense.

I have tried the folling:

```
Dim table As DataTable = TryCast(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)

If table IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        Dim txLName As String = TryCast(row.ItemArray(1), String)
        Dim txName As String = TryCast(row.ItemArray(2), String)
        Dim txEmail As String = TryCast(row.ItemArray(3), String)
        Dim txRole As String = TryCast(row.ItemArray(4), String)
        Dim txPhone As String = TryCast(row.ItemArray(5), String)
        Dim drpEmpl As String = TryCast(row.ItemArray(6), String)
        If drpEmpl = "Other" Then
            drpEmpl = txtOther.Text
        Else
            drpEmpl = TryCast(row.ItemArray(6), String)
        End If
```

I am getting an error that `txtOther.Text` is not declared and may be inaccessible.

`drpEmpl` is the name of the `DropDownList`.

I have tried:

```
drpEmpl = gridview1.FindControl("txtOther")
```

But same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I would try.

1. User enters text into txtOther and submits page
2. Take what user submitter and store it into viewstate variable (some array may be best for this in case more values are needed)
3. Modify your txtEmployer and add event handler for OnLoad
4. In the event handler for OnLoad you just add another option for drop down list.

   ```
   foreach (string s in ArrayOfPreviouslyAddedValues){

       ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(s, s));
   }
   ```

Another option is to store all values for all options in some background source (database or what ever) and to programatically databind values to your drop down list.

This is C# but you see the point.